# Здравствуйте, вопрос по drag & drops

Tags: javascript

Хотел бы перемещать список внутри и в пределах контейнера(ниже эти элементы присвоены переменным). По оси X движение хорошо отрабатывает, по оси Y при срабатывании события mousemove, список резко падает на максимально-установленную координату по Y(в коде ниже) и лежит там. Вертикальное перемещение списка все же возможно, но только в случае если курсор находится много выше списка и в таком случае чем больше амплитуда движения курсора, тем сильнее можно подбросить список наверх.

```js
   (function () {
   var list = document.querySelector('.list');
   var container = document.querySelector('.container4');
   list.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
   list.style.position = 'absolute';
   var LOCATION = {
       X_MIN: 0,
       X_MAX: container.offsetWidth - list.offsetWidth,
       Y_MIN: 0,
       Y_MAX: container.offsetHeight - list.offsetHeight
   };
   var setControlArea = function () {
       if (list.offsetLeft <= LOCATION.X_MIN) {
           list.style.left = LOCATION.X_MIN + 'px';
       }
       if (list.offsetLeft >= LOCATION.X_MAX) {
           list.style.left = LOCATION.X_MAX + 'px';
       }
       if (list.offsetTop <= LOCATION.Y_MIN) {
           list.style.top = LOCATION.Y_MIN + 'px';
       }
       if (list.offsetTop >= LOCATION.Y_MAX) {
           list.style.top = LOCATION.Y_MAX + 'px';
       }
   };
   list.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt) {
       evt.preventDefault();
       var startCoordinates = {
           X: evt.clientX,
           Y: evt.clientY
       };
       var listMouseMoveHandler = function (moveEvt) {
           moveEvt.preventDefault();
           var shift = {
               X: startCoordinates.X - moveEvt.clientX,
               Y: startCoordinates.Y - moveEvt.clientY
           };
           startCoordinates = {
               X: moveEvt.clientX,
               Y: moveEvt.clientY
           };

           list.style.left = list.offsetLeft - shift.X + 'px';
           list.style.top = list.offsetTop - shift.Y + 'px';
           setControlArea();
       };
       var listMouseUpHandler = function () {
           document.removeEventListener('mousemove', listMouseMoveHandler);
           document.removeEventListener('mouseup', listMouseUpHandler);
       };
       document.addEventListener('mousemove', listMouseMoveHandler);
       document.addEventListener('mouseup', listMouseUpHandler);
   })
   }());
```

```css
    .container4 {
      padding: 50px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 150px;
      margin: 150px auto 0;
      background-color: #89a1fd;
      position: relative;
    }

    .container4 > ul {
      max-width: 130px;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container4">
  <ul class="list" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="">
      <input id="radio-button-1" type="radio" class="" checked name="reviews__radio-button">
      <label for="radio-button-1" class="">
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="reviews__radio-item">
      <input id="radio-button-2" type="radio" class="" name="reviews__radio-button">
      <label for="radio-button-2" class="">
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="reviews__radio-item">
      <input id="radio-button-3" type="radio" class="" name="reviews__radio-button">
      <label for="radio-button-3" class="">
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: что-то не воспроизводится пример. Подфиксите код

Comment: теперь пример воспроизводится